# Django to respond to only specific apps

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm testing out Django and want it to respond to only certain apps, for instance admin and polls (from the tutorial). The rest of the time I want just regular apache. I was able to do this using port forwarding. Specifically, I modified httpd.conf to be:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:8081
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite
ServerName <ServerIPAddress>
#ErrorLog /home/ec2-user/testproject/logs/apache_error.log
#CustomLog /home/djangotest/helloworld/logs/apache_access.log combined
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
etc...
```

However, I want to get rid of the 8081, and just make it work on the default port 80? At the moment, both mysite:8081/polls/ and mysite:8081/admin/ both work.

Here's the wsgi file in case it's needed:

```
import os
import sys

path= '/home/ec2-user/srv/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Edit:
Here's the urls.py of mysite (not polls).

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls',namespace = "polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here's the urls.py for polls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     #ex: /polls/
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
     #ex: /polls/5
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
     # ex: /polls/5/results/
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
     # ex: /polls/5/vote/
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the WSGIScriptAlias portion of your apache2 config like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /polls /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
```

Also since you are planning to run multiple Django apps on the server, instead of using: **os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")**, change it to:

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
```

From your mysite urls change **r'^polls/'** to **r'^'**. You have to do this because apache2 aliases the **/polls** to a **/** request to the django app. (Same explains why you have to type: /polls/admin).

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html)

**WSGIDaemonProcess** is the recommended way of deploying multiple Django apps.(you will find lot of examples in stack).

And yes, you can use the above settings with **port:80**.

For more details you can see this [link](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/).

Comment: After making this change, both my admin and polls site are 404. The urls I'm using are <MyServerIP>/polls and <MyServerIP>/admin. However, that 404 is served via Django.

Comment: from your **mysite urls** change **r'^polls/'** to **r'^'** .Does it work now ?

Comment: It's better, polls now works but admin points to polls as well. Is that because there is no admin folder under mysite? Can you please let me know how to fix it? Also, can you explain why this worked? I'm still trying to learn! Thank you!

Comment: For admin to work, please remove the **WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py** line from the apache2 config. Now admin will also work fine.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix it. I get a 404 - this time served by apache. The reason that your change to polls worked (I think) is that r'^' matches to anything. When I got rid of the WSGIScriptAlias for admin, it doesn't no to even use wsgi.py no?

Comment: Go-To: **<YourServerIP>/polls/admin**.

Comment: Wow, ok that worked. Can you please edit your post and let me know exactly why? What will happen if I install a new app? I understand I add it to WSGIScriptAlias in httpd.conf but now I don't need to modify urls.py in mysite? How does that work? And why does admin now work through polls rather than directly? If I install a new app, say "X", will "X"/admin and "X"/polls bring me to the same page? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Ok, last question, so if I need to use multiple apps, I now need to install WSGIDaemonProcess? I can't just add inter WSGIScriptAlias?

Comment: No, you don't have to, the above method will also work fine.
You don't have to install **WSGIDaemonProcess**, its not a package.
[Link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), 
[Link2](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)